# How do I get a users (who is not my facebook friend) profile pic

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

01 to connect to facebook on my desktop app.

How do I get a users (who is not my facebook friend) profile pic.

Comment: Is this assuming that user has lenient privacy settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the ID/Username of the user, this is the URL (no need for API):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/UID/picture
```

If you want a larger image, try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/UID/picture?type=large
```

If you don't have the ID/Username, but do have an e-mail address - I have found a trick. Do a search via the API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mail@domain.com&type=User
```

This should give you a UID, that you can use in the above image URL.